# jQuery script to add/remove classes successfully adds the class but cannot remove the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So essentially I would like an element that when clicked, triggers a jQuery script that either adds or removes a class (in this case I am adding a class which changes the background-image css attribute) to only that specific element.

```js
function readMore() {
    var subID = event.target.id;
    var footerTarget = $('[id='+subID+'][class="articleFooter"]');
    var newTarget = $('[id='+subID+'][class="showArticlePara"]');

    newTarget.toggle();

    var footerTarget = $('[id='+subID+'][class="articleFooter"]');

    if (newTarget.css("display") == "block") {
        footerTarget.addClass("changeBackgroundImage");
    }
    else {
        footerTarget.removeClass("changeBackgroundImage");
    }

    alert(footerTarget.class());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

```css
.articleSection {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;

 background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 border-radius: 2px;

 box-sizing:border-box; 
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.articleContent {
 /*height: 70px;*/
 padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px;

 box-sizing:border-box; 
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.articleVotes {
}
.voteBox {
}
.articleFooter {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 content: 'more';

 background-image:url('../Images/Icons/showMoreBlack13030.png');
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;

 transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.articleFooter:hover {
 background-image: url('../Images/Icons/chevron13040Blue.png');
}
.changeBackgroundImage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 content: 'less';

 background-image:url('../Images/Icons/showLessBlack13030.png');
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 15px center;

 transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.changeBackgroundImage:hover {
 background-image: url('../Images/Icons/chevron13040BlueRotated.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="articleSection">
    <div class="articleContent">
        <h2>Exciting new study shows that in any male group, at least one is gay</h2>
        <div class="showArticlePara" id="one">
            <p>
                I really hope it's Luke, he's cute af.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="articleVotes">
        <div class="voteBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="articleFooter" id="one" onclick="readMore()"></div>
</div>
```

So as I click `.articleFooter` with `id=subID` I already have the display of the paragraph associated with it changing display property using simple jQuery `toggle()`. I have tried using `toggleClass()` but this only adds the class and doesn't remove it on the second click.

I've finally tried an `if/else` statement which checks if the paragraph that was affected earlier is `display: none` and adds or removes a class based on the result but once again this only successfully adds the class but fails to remove the same class on the second click.

Thanks for any suggestions and/or help.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hm3y3848/

Comment: You're using the same id `one` for multiple elements. ID are meant to be unique.

Comment: @Titus I know, I'm aware, bad etiquette and all that but it seemed like a good idea at the time and I'm hoping that it isn't affecting my current problem so in essence; one step at a time.

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey - It's not just bad etiquette, it actually impacts the functionality of both JS and jQuery . . . for example, selections (in JS and jQuery) on an id that is in the DOM multiple times, will only ever return the first element that has that id assigned to it.

Comment: Is not a matter of **bad etiquette** Using the same ID more then once creates unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @talemyn @Titus Okay I understand but in the context that I'm using repeated IDs I am selecting the class + id of any element and for any class there is only one element with an id of say `one`. For instance in this case I have used the id multiple times so as to "classify" the group of elements into one functional block, I understand that there are more advanced ways of doing this but I'm not writing very complex scripts so I'd like to keep it easy to understand as I'm very slowly learning JS/jQuery.

Comment: Use `newTarget.toggleClass('changeBackgroundImage');` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hm3y3848/1/

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey - It doesn't matter if you are adding the class into the selector . . . it will still only return the first instance of the element with that id and class, because of the id needing to be uninque.

Comment: @talemyn _first instance of the element with that id and class_ - exactly! In my code there is only one element with both the `id` and `class` that I specify while there are multiple elements with any one `class` and also with any one `id`.

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey - ahhh . . . I see what you're saying.  Still . . . you should fix it.   :D   Either way, I provided an answer that I believe will actually solve your problem below.   ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue (in addition to the "duplicate id" problem ;) ), is how you are selecting your elements:

```
var footerTarget = $('[id='+subID+'][class="articleFooter"]');
```

By using `[class="articleFooter"]`, you are saying "get me the element whose class **IS** "articleFooter" (i.e., `class="articleFooter"`) . . . however, after you've added the "changeBackgroundImage", the class of the element is now "articleFooter" **AND** "changeBackgroundImage" (i.e., `class="articleFooter changeBackgroundImage"`), so it is not matching.

There are a couple of ways to fix this . . .

1) the more "common" way that people usually do these kinds of selections is to use the "id" and "class" selector shorthands in jQuery:  "*#MY_ID*" for ids and "*.MY_CLASS*" for classes.  Example:

```
$("#" + subID + ".articleFooter")
```

Or, in a more efficient way:

```
$("#" + subID).filter(".articleFooter")
```

In both cases, if will match the element with both that id and class (though, the element may also have other classes).

2) the less common way, but what would also resolve this issue, is to use a different attribute pattern in your existing code.  You are using `[attribute='value']` which means that the value of the attribute must be **exactly** the value in your selector (because of the `=` in your selector).

In order to allow for other classes to be in the element's class list, you can use the "contains" selector for the attribute:  `[attribute*='value']` which means that the value of the attribute must contain, but is not limited to, the value in the selector.

Either should work, but the first approach is what you will see more often, because the shorthand is easier to type.   ;)

And PLEASE fix your duplicate id problem, or you will continue to see other issues.   :D

Comment: Can I take you for dinner please. I think I love you. I'm sorry for anything even remotely rude I said to you. `[attribute*='value']` saved me ergo you saved me. Like genuinely let me kiss you

Comment: LOL . . . We can forgo the dinner and kisses . . . just happy to have been able to help you out of a jam.  Keep learning.   ;)

Answer (score -1):

The `readMore()` function has first line

```
event.target.id
```

From where will you receive `event` object? This is throwing `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

**Solution 1**

1) Pass `id` while calling `readMore` function in a native way

```
<div class="articleFooter" id="one" onclick="readMore(this.id)"></div>
```

2) Pass it in the parameter and change the first line in the function

```
function readMore(id) {
    var subID = id;
    .
    .
}
```

3) There is no function as `.class()`. Remove this line

```
alert(footerTarget.class());
```

**Solution 2**

Another Approach is to use jQuery's way of handling events, since you are already using `jQuery`

```
<div class="articleFooter" id="one"></div>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".articleFooter").click(function() {
        var subID = $(this).attr('id');
        var footerTarget = $('[id=' + subID + '][class="articleFooter"]');
        var newTarget = $('[id=' + subID + '][class="showArticlePara"]');

        newTarget.toggle();

        var footerTarget = $('[id=' + subID + '][class="articleFooter"]');

        if (newTarget.css("display") == "block") {
            footerTarget.addClass("changeBackgroundImage");
        } else {
            footerTarget.removeClass("changeBackgroundImage");
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hm3y3848/2/)

Comment: A down vote without a reason.. Explain the reason so we all can learn.

Comment: I like this solution of changing what I've already done but it doesn't fix the class toggle, it still seems sporadic. In this case it adds the class on the second click but doesn't remove it at any point after?

Comment: Wasn't me anyway, I like the way you've triggered the event but it doesn't solve my current problem